# Editext input type behaves weirdly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, settings

I have 4 edittext with input type as numberPassword and each having max length of 1. As soon as a number is entered I am programmatically changing the focus to the next field. I want the numbers to be masked as soon as the focus is being changed to next field, but what's happening is unpredictable some time when I am at 3 then only 1 gets masked or when I am at 4 then 3 and 2 gets masked but not 1, sometimes none of them gets masked but as soon as I manaually focus on any feild it gets masked. I want to have some consistency that too when the focus changes to next field the last field should be masked.[image]

**Xml Layout :**

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1">

               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_mpin_2"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_mpin_4"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/et_mpin_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_mpin_3"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/et_mpin_2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_mpin_1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java code :**

```
et_mpin1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
//                et_mpin1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
//                et_mpin1.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // checking before only because for max lenght 1 start is always going to be 0
                if (before == 0) {

                    et_mpin2.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        et_mpin2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // checking before only because for max lenght 1 start is always going to be 0
                if (before == 0) {
                    et_mpin3.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    et_mpin1.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        et_mpin3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // checking before only because for max lenght 1 start is always going to be 0
                if (before == 0) {
                    et_mpin4.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    et_mpin2.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        et_mpin4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // checking before only because for max lenght 1 start is always going to be 0
                if (before == 0) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_mpin4.getWindowToken(), 0);
                } else {
                    et_mpin3.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Hide password forcefully,

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD, 0);
```

> Note : It will not show any characters, Directly DOTs will be
>   displayed without any delay inside your View.

Comment: can you give a little example how exactly it can be used with edittext

Comment: @Sunny you don't have to do with `EditText` you have to simply write in the `Activity`.

Comment: @Sunny glad to know that.